# How to bind a privileged port without privileges?

Tags: jsvc

I have a piece of daemon code that is supposed to be invoked by jsvc. The code needs to bind to a privileged port below 1024. I do not have root access so I am thinking of authbind. I tried:

```
authbind --deep jsvc ...
```

but in `jsvc.err`, it still says:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably forgot to configure authbind.

If you want to allow user `jo` to bind port `80` you have to run the following commands as root.

```
root@lappy:~# touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
root@lappy:~# chown jo:jo /etc/authbind/byport/80
root@lappy:~# chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

Read the [Running network services as a non-root user](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/386) from the Debian Administration Guide for more information.